# Chip component of MUI in React not rendering on first click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, chips

I am using MUI Select for multi-select option and showing the final values after some modification as MUI Chips. Now when i click add the chip does not shows at that instant however If I change any value of name and suffix the page renders and then the chip shows. Maybe i am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

```
import { useState,  } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {OutlinedInput, MenuItem, Chip, useTheme, Select} from '@mui/material';

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const EditUser =styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
`
const Label = styled.label`
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
`
const LabelInputWrapper = styled.div`
    margin-bottom:25px;
    flex:1 0 30%;
    display: ${(props) => props.disp};

`
const Adduserformcont = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin:10px;
`
const AddChrgWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`

const names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
  'Ralph Hubbard',
  'Omar Alexander',
  'Carlos Abbott',
  'Miriam Wagner',
  'Bradley Wilkerson',
  'Virginia Andrews',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}
const desigSuffix = ["I","II", "III", "IV"];

const EditUsers = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState({})
  const [finalValue, setFinalValue] =useState([])

  
  const onChangeUserForm = (event) => {
    if(event.target.name === 'selectMultiAddnCharg'){
      setPersonName(event.target.value)
    }
    let temp = {...value, [event.target.name]:event.target.value}
    setValue(temp);
    console.log(temp)
  
  }
  const addWithSuffix = () => {
    let tempArray = finalValue;
    tempArray.push(`${value.adnCharge} (${value.desgnSuffix})`)
    setFinalValue(tempArray)
    
  } 

  return (

    <>

    <form> 

        <AddChrgWrapper>
        <Label>Select name</Label>
        <Select
          name='selectMultiAddnCharg'
          multiple
          displayEmpty
          value={personName}
          onChange={onChangeUserForm}
          input={<OutlinedInput />}
          renderValue={(selected) => {
            if (selected.length === 0) {
              return <em>Select name</em>;
            }

            return selected.join(', ');
          }}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
          inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
        >
          <MenuItem disabled value="">
            <em>Placeholder</em>
          </MenuItem>
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={name}
              value={name}
              style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
            >
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
        </AddChrgWrapper>
      <LabelInputWrapper name="adnCharge">
                <Label>Name</Label>
                <select name="adnCharge" onChange={onChangeUserForm}>                
                    <option>Select</option>
                    {personName.map((item,index) => <option key={index}>{item}</option>)}
                </select>  
      </LabelInputWrapper>
      <LabelInputWrapper name="desgnSuffix" >
                <Label>Suffix</Label>
                <select name="desgnSuffix" onChange={onChangeUserForm}>                
                    <option>Select</option>
                    {desigSuffix.map((item,index) => <option key={index}>{item}</option>)}
                </select>  
      </LabelInputWrapper> 
      <button type="button" onClick={(e)=>addWithSuffix(e)}>Add</button>
      <div>{finalValue.map((item, index)=><Chip key={index} label={item}/>)}</div>   
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default EditUsers
```

Comment: What do you need as an output? Do you want to be able to view the chips when the multi-select option is selected? Please elaborate more. Will be glad to help

Comment: I want to view the chips when i click add button.

Comment: I am able to view the chips with your code without any change if I modify "Name" or "Suffix" select button. If I only change the multi-select , I am still able to view the chips but with values as "undefined". It is because you are displaying the values of adnCharge and desgnSuffix in chips, but not the value of selectMultiAddnCharg

Comment: After selecting one Name and  One Suffix and then clicking Add button for first time, i should be able to view the Chips but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `addWithSuffix` function, When you declared `tempArray` it's not a new array, but you still mutate the `finalValue` state directly, and this's not allowd.
From React docs:

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state.

You can declare new array variable based on old state
`let tempArray = [...finalValue]`
or use first argument of `setFinalValue` that is old state

```
const addWithSuffix = () => {
    let tempArray = [...finalValue];
    tempArray.push(`${value.adnCharge} (${value.desgnSuffix})`)
    setFinalValue(tempArray)
}
```

**OR**

```
const addWithSuffix = () => {
   setFinalValue(state => state.concat(`${value.adnCharge} (${value.desgnSuffix})`))
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
const names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
  'Ralph Hubbard',
  'Omar Alexander',
  'Carlos Abbott',
  'Miriam Wagner',
  'Bradley Wilkerson',
  'Virginia Andrews',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}
const desigSuffix = ["I","II", "III", "IV"];

const EditUsers = () => {
const { useState } = React
const { OutlinedInput, MenuItem, Chip, useTheme, Select } = MaterialUI;
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState({})
  const [finalValue, setFinalValue] =useState([])

  
  const onChangeUserForm = (event) => {
    if(event.target.name === 'selectMultiAddnCharg'){
      setPersonName(event.target.value)
    }
    let temp = {...value, [event.target.name]:event.target.value}
    setValue(temp);
    console.log(temp)
  
  }
  const addWithSuffix = () => {
    // let tempArray = finalValue;
    const newVal = `${value.adnCharge} (${value.desgnSuffix})`
    // tempArray.push(newVal)
    setFinalValue(state => state.concat(newVal))
  } 

  return (

    <>

    <form> 

        <div>
        <label>Select name</label>
        <Select
          name='selectMultiAddnCharg'
          multiple
          displayEmpty
          value={personName}
          onChange={onChangeUserForm}
          input={<OutlinedInput />}
          renderValue={(selected) => {
            if (selected.length === 0) {
              return <em>Select name</em>;
            }

            return selected.join(', ');
          }}

          inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
        >
          <MenuItem disabled value="">
            <em>Placeholder</em>
          </MenuItem>
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={name}
              value={name}
              style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
            >
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
        </div>
      <div name="adnCharge">
                <label>Name</label>
                <select name="adnCharge" onChange={onChangeUserForm}>                
                    <option>Select</option>
                    {personName.map((item,index) => <option key={index}>{item}</option>)}
                </select>  
      </div>
      <div name="desgnSuffix" >
                <label>Suffix</label>
                <select name="desgnSuffix" onChange={onChangeUserForm}>                
                    <option>Select</option>
                    {desigSuffix.map((item,index) => <option key={index}>{item}</option>)}
                </select>  
      </div> 
      <button type="button" onClick={(e)=>addWithSuffix(e)}>Add</button>
      <div>{finalValue.map((item, index)=><Chip key={index} label={item}/>)}</div>   
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
  
  const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<EditUsers />);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Can you explain a bit why it was not working and how the change has helped?

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope the explanation is clear.